# How to have a fixed simulation time in uvm

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

is it possible to have a fixed simulation time in the uvm-framwork? Normally i start the simulation and run it for a fixed time in a *.tcl file (e.g. run 1ms).

P.S: i am new in uvm

Comment: usually the test itself defines how long it would run. It does not matter if the test is written in uvm, or just verilog.  It makes no sense to limit it with fixed time by external tool, unless it runs too long, like several hours or days.  You need to provide more info about your requirements.

Comment: thanks, my DUT is a spi slave device. i initialized it and then i watch  the output with defined assertions (direct verification). Therefore i ask for a fixed sim time.

Comment: Still, what is the point of a test which might have no chance to finish in limited physical time on a generic computer which is prone to speed variations due to other tasks and ios. Just initialization of the test environment (in particular with uvm) could take much more than 1ms. So, your test might not even have a chance to start before it gets killed.

Comment: ok, can someone give me a recommendation for a uvm-framework-website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UVM has an objection mechanism used to end tests. Components raise objections and then lower objections to ending current run_phase. All you have to do is in the run_phase of your test, or some other component.

```
phase.raise_objection(this);
#1ms;
phase.drop_objection(this);
```

This assumes there are no other objections in your testbench. You might want to read http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsDVCon2011_UVM_TerminationTechniques.pdf

Also, more info on the UVM framework can be found [here](https://verificationacademy.com/courses/UVM-Framework-One-Bite-at-a-Time).